# Edit Information only from the logged user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design, identity

I have the following tables: Company 1 -> * Stores 1 -> * Products

And I'm using the following route to edit information:
Company/1/Store/3/Product/4/Edit

How can I secure that a user that doesn't belong to this company doesn't change the ids on the url and change information from others company?
I'm already storing the user companyId on login so I can perform this validation on Stores Controller because I know that a Store have a CompanyId associated and I just check if that companyId is equals to the logged user CompanyId. But now from the products I don't have any association with the company itself only with the store.

My question is, should I create a property CompanyId or UserId that created that product on the stores table, or maybe I should like use a join on the query and say db.Store.Find(UrlStoreId).Include(Products).FirstOrDefault(o => o.CompanyId == loggedUserCompanyId);

I would like to know the conventions for this type of problems in an Application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MVC controllers, the current session's user CompanyId can be recorded in session state and compared against each call. If the IDs do not match for any reason then dump the user session and kick them back to the login screen. For Web API controllers you should include a CompanyId in the claims for the Auth Token to perform the same type of validation. Again if a mismatch is found, the violation attempt should be logged and the token invalidated (if supported)

As for the joins, if you set up the references between your entities then you should be able to always enforce the Ids..

given a URL with:
Company/1/Store/3/Product/4/Edit

```
if(loggedInUserCompanyId != urlCompanyId)
  // Dump session, kick out.

var product = context.Companies
  .Where(c=> c.CompanyId == urlCompanyId)
  .SelectMany(c=> c.Stores.Where(s=> s.StoreId == urlStoreId)
     .SelectMany(s => s.Products))
  .SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == urlProductId);
```

This will enforce the hierarchy for your domain down to the company and store to ensure that someone doesn't try and "tweak" something like the Store ID or Product ID to gain access to another company's data. If you have an API call such as /Product/4/Edit then you should always ensure that your Claims in your auth token contain enough info (CompanyId) to ensure that you can validate that an API call for Product Id 4 belongs to the correct company.

There's bound to be a lot more you can/should do to ensure data is restricted, but this should provide you with a minimal starting point. Ideally you will want authorization checks as deep as possible in your code structure to ensure that checks like this are not missed. I lean towards the repository pattern to wrap calls to the DbContext rather than having controllers and such accessing the context directly. In that way, even though my repositories return IQueryable, they enforce the authorization so that controller code searching for data don't need to worry about forgetting to include "Company" checks.

Other options include enforcing Authorization at the database level, an option I believe is available in SQL Server where company data could be partitioned separately. AFAIK this would involve separate user accounts per tenant in the database server. A manual flavour of this is to adopt something like Schema-per-tenant or database-per-tenant which ensures that data is not exposed between tenants.

Comment: Hello Steve Py,

Thanks for you answer, It sounds great all that you've said. Authorization at the Database is new to me and I'll take a look soon. I'm still not using Repositories and Unit of Work just because I'm still developing the project and I don't need it for now. I just have one more question, if my route is "Manage/{storeId]/Product/{productId} How could I perform this validation without having the companyId on the Url? This is actually my route right now, I just messed up in my earlier question. Should I include Company on Url, Change database struture, or use include?